# How do I retrieve all rows from a database and store in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I am not sure how I would do this I've been messing around with it for hours to no avail.

I want to get all the data from the database and display it in a grid view.

So far I've got the HTML side

```
<%@ Page Title="Add a pet type" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PetView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pets_In_Need.PetView" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>View Pets</h1>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdViewPets" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" EnableViewState="False">
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Pet Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="age" HeaderText="Date of Birth" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Pet Date of Birth" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="Gender" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Pet Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="breed" HeaderText="Breed" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Pet Breed" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="weight" HeaderText="Weight(lbs)" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Pet Weight" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="friendliness" HeaderText="Friendliness(1-10)" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Pet Friendliness" />
          </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
     </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And this.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Pets_In_Need
{
    public partial class PetView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create new DB connection
            DB pinDB = new DB();
            //Open DB connection
            pinDB.Open();


        }
    }
}
```

Where do I go from here I've read many other posts and tutorials however I can't seem to put that into my own work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First you need to acquire the data from the db:

```
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [tableName]";
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectQuery, con))
            {
                //Populate the datatable with the results
                da.Fill(table);
            }
        }
```

Once you have a DataTable you bind it to the GridView:

```
        grdViewPets.DataSource = table;
        grdViewPets.DataBind();
```

You'll want to ensure the columns in the DataTable match with the columns in the GridView.

Comment: using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))

Thanks this helps a lot could you just briefly explain the connectionstring part to me?

Comment: ConnectionString is a string with all of the information needed to connect to your database. One simple way of getting the connection string to your DB is, using Visual Studio, open the Server Explorer (ctrl-alt-s), right-click Data Connections and Add Connection. Then you input the IP or DB file name if local, valid authentication etc. and select the default database. Once the server exists underneath Data Connections, you can copy the Connection String from Properties. Something like: `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StronglyTypedContext-20150714230644;Integrated Security=True`